# Is it asp.net Core Cookie Authentication without identity session stateless yes or no?

Tags: session, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have been looking a lot of tutorials and always they say that the asp.net Core `cookie authentication` the user stays authenticated on the server side in a Session object with a session Id. But in the CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs `SignInAsync` only save the sessionId when `Options.SessionStore` exists, if this is not the case I suppose that in each request is send all encrypted claims without the need to store all data in to `Session object` (like token authentication). So, Can someone clarify it to me please.

CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs source code;

```
   var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(signInContext.Principal, signInContext.Properties, signInContext.Scheme.Name);



              if (Options.SessionStore != null)

              {

                  if (_sessionKey != null)

                    {

                        await Options.SessionStore.RemoveAsync(_sessionKey);

                    }

                    _sessionKey = await Options.SessionStore.StoreAsync(ticket);

                    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(

                        new ClaimsIdentity(

                            new[] { new Claim(SessionIdClaim, _sessionKey, ClaimValueTypes.String, Options.ClaimsIssuer) },

                            Options.ClaimsIssuer));

                    ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, null, Scheme.Name);

                }



                var cookieValue = Options.TicketDataFormat.Protect(ticket, GetTlsTokenBinding());
```

Comment: I don't believe SessionStore means an asp.net session.  According to the docs it's an "optional container to store a ticket across requests"

Answer (score 1):

CookieAuthentication can work just fine without enabling Session.

All the claims are serialized into the cookie and deserialized into a ClaimsPrinicpal by the Authentication middleware on each request.

So if you mean stateless as in no session state needed, yes, the state is in the cookie, passed with each request.

Answer (score 0):

No.

To prove this, create a new app. Register a new user. Delete your database and recreate it. When you return to your app you will be treated as though you are still authenticated.

If anything, the cookie is simply used as a cache that lives beyond the session. Like any cache, you must check if it’s stale, which means synchronizing state between client and server.

And, as Phil Karlton said, there are only two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation and naming things.

Achieving statelessness should be treated as a goal, but not a religious mandate.

Answer (score 0):

By default, without Session installed, it is stateless.

A simple test to prove it:

- return a cookie to your client via CookieAuthentication/SignIn
- save the cookie value somewhere
- then SignOut (the server returns a SetCookie to reset the value of the authentication cookie)
- Send a request from the client reusing the value obtained in 1.
- despite the SignOut phase you will still be authenticated! If by default you had a server side session mechanism in place, this cookie would have become invalid because the session would have been destroyed and the server wouldn't be able to match the cookie with the session.